# Can a given symmetric matrix be written as a linear combination of the identity and a rank-$1$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Given an invertible symmetric matrix $M$, is there a way to determine whether it can be written as $$M = a v v^T + b \mathrm{I}$$ for some scalars $a,b \neq 0$ and a vector $v$? I'm given matrix $M$ and want to find $a, b$ and $v$.

Comment: If $b \neq 0$, then $bI=M-avv^T$ is invertible so $M$ must have rank at least $n-1$. Else, $M$ must have rank at most $1$. In general, $M-bI$ has rank at most $1$ so $b$ is a zero of $\chi_M$ with multiplicity at least $n-1$.

Comment: Thanks @Mindlack, this is helpful. What is $\chi_M$, the characteristic polynomial ?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Note that $avv^T$ is **not** how a general rank-$1$ matrix looks like, so the title asks a different question than the post. (Though it would be fixed if you added "symmetric".)

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of the form $M=avv^T+bI$, then $M$ is clearly symmetric and we may always suppose that
$v^Tv=1$, by replacing $v$ with $v'=(v^Tv)^{-1/2}v$, and $a$ with $a'= (v^Tv)a$.

Assuming henceforth that $v^Tv=1$, observe that
$$
  Mv=avv^Tv+bv = (a+b)v,
  $$
and that, for every vector $u$ perpendicular to $v$, we have
$$
  Mu=avv^Tu+bu = bu.
  $$
Therefore  the spectrum of $M$ coincides with  $\{a+b,b\}$, where the multiplicity of $a+b$ is $1$ (provided $a\neq 0$), and the multiplicity of $b$
is $n-1$.

Conversely, every symmetric matrix whose spectrum consists of exactly two points, say $\lambda _1$ and $\lambda _2$, with multiplicities
1 and $n-1$, respectively, may be written as
$$
  M=avv^T+bI,
  $$
where $b$ is the spectral value with multiplicity $n-1$, namely $b=\lambda _2$,  and  $a=\lambda _1-\lambda _2$.  Finally, $v$ is any unit
eigenvector associated to $\lambda _1$.